# Setting different environment per git branch

Tags: php, git, environment-variables, branch

I have a few things i'm confused about concerning best practice setting up different environments for branches in my php projects.

I usually work in Laravel and use the default version for setting environment (based on gethostname()). This works fine for local and production server. But now I want to start using branches, and naturally need to be able to work on all branches locally. So, I need to do something different for environments, since gethostname would be the same. I figure environment variables is the best way?

If so, I do this in .htaccess (SenEnv)? Or is there a better way? 
And what happens when i change branch? I need to manually change this everytime? Or, again, is there a better way?

Any feedback/tip appreciated. Either answers to my questions, or if there are other ways entirely I should consider.

Thanks! :)

Comment: What is different between "environments"?

Comment: Is it unclear that with environment I mean a varaible in my php project thats used for e.g. setting the correct database connection? Im not talking about machine setup, php version etc.

Comment: Yes, it was unclear. Then that leads to a different question. What are you using branches for? Admittedly, as one person, I have only seen a small subset of projects, but I have never seen a project where different branches referred to different environments.

Comment: E.g. a site I built a little while a go for a client is going change the login/user-system. This requires a considerable change to the database and will also take some time. The site is quite new and still needs bug fixing and also new features. I want to be able to swap between master branch and "new user system" branch and have different databases for each branch.

Comment: Then perhaps a description of how you intend to handle this would be useful. If I were doing it, I would have a test system with the new database on which I was testing the changes(since I don't see a good way of testing the database changes on the production system). I would clone the original repo and use the clone for the test system. I'd set the productiion repo as another remote on the clone, so I could merge in changes being made to the production system. Then I would make changes on the test repo until I was satisfied with it.

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm unclear here. I dont really have know how I intend to do it. Thats basically what I'm asking - how "you guys" are doing it.
I have considered the method you're describing - and will probably end up doing it that way. I just assumed people usually only had one setup/system and swapped branches instead. Thanks for your input and time :)